# How to change the ouput color in the terminal of Visual Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, colors, spyder

Im a  Python programmer and I have swithced IDE. I have switched from Spyder to Visual Code. Untill now I can say that Visual Code is way better then Spyder,  but I have some problems with the output color in the terminal.

**This is my output in Spyder:**
[image]

**This is my output in Visual Code:**
[image]

As you can see in Spyder the output is written in the **White** color, whilst the path is written in **Green**. In Visual code the whole output (path + output) is written in **Blue**. I prefer the color settings used in Spyder, because Im very color orientated. I think its very nice to distuinguish between Path and Output using different colors.

**So my question is:** How can I give the output and the Path a different color in Visual Code?

Comment: -You could refer to this [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors) to change the color of the Integrated Terminal. Also, you can use VS Code extensions to provide related functions, such as Code Runner.

Comment: @Jill Cheng have you also changed your output color?

Answer (score 6):

In VS Code, we can change the color of the internal terminal, but currently it is not supported to change the color of the terminal output separately.

You can refer to this link that I have submitted: [Is it possible to set the color of the content output from the VS Code internal terminal?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116832)

However, I use the following two workarounds and you could refer to them:

1. Use special code output:

> ```
>     print("\033[31mThis is red font.\033[0m")
>     print("\033[32mThis is green font.\033[0m")
>     print("\033[33mThis is yellow font.\033[0m")
>     print("\033[34mThis is blue font.\033[0m")
>     print("\033[38mThis is the default font. \033[0m")  # More than 37 will display the default font.
> ```

[image]

2. Use VS Code extension: For example: Code Runner

[image]

Comment: can we have a private conversation?

Comment: @TangerCity -What problem did you encounter? We can discuss technical issues here, and its content will help others who encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
# function to print the output, the text will be highlighted with green color
# run this function once before start coding
def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
  print("\033[32m", end="")
  print(*args, **kwargs)
  print("\033[0m", end="")
  
new_print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).